# How do I perform this query using sailsjs ORM (waterline)

Tags: node.js, orm, sails.js, waterline

How do I perform this query?

```
SELECT * FROM blog
GROUP BY MONTH(createdAt)
```

What I've tried:

```
Blog.find()
.groupBy({MONTH:'createdAt'})
.exec(function(err,months){

        res.view({
          layout: 'blogLayout',
          archive:months
        });


 });
```

Gives me Error: Cannot groupBy without a calculation

Answer (score 4):

Waterline (the ORM used by sails) at this point only supports using groupBy in combination with sum(), count() etc. You can find the line of code that verifies this here: https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-mongo/blob/master/lib/query/aggregate.js#L43.